# How can I bind a context menu on a LineSymbol in ESRI?

Tags: wpf, binding, contextmenu, symbols

I have created a ControlTemplate for a LineSymbol:

```
            <esri:SimpleLineSymbol 
        x:Key="PolylineSymbol" 
        Width="3"
        >
        <esri:SimpleLineSymbol.ControlTemplate>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid
                    >
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
    ...
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
    ...
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Path 
                        x:Name="Element" Fill="{x:Null}"
                        Stroke="Navy" StrokeThickness="3"
                                StrokeLineJoin="Round" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round">
                        <Path.ContextMenu>
                            <ContextMenu 
                                x:Name="popUpMenu"
                                DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type esri:Graphic}}}">
                                <MenuItem 
                                    x:Name="miSelect"
                                    Header="Select" 
                                    IsCheckable="True"
                                    IsChecked="{Binding Selected, FallbackValue=False}"
                                    />
                                ...
                            </ContextMenu>
                        </Path.ContextMenu>
                    </Path>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </esri:SimpleLineSymbol.ControlTemplate>
    </esri:SimpleLineSymbol>
```

Everything works well, except the binding in IsChecked on the "Select" menu item: Since neither Symbol, nor Graphic inherits from FrameworkElement no binding expression will take me from here to the Contained Graphic of this SimpleLineSymbol.

I have also tried a Click event (which gives a sender, a command (which supports a parameter) or a MouseRightButtonDown event (on the graphic,) - no method takes me from the right-clicked point on the path of the Symbol to the containing Graphic...

The DataContext of the Menu looks OK in the designer of VS2012, but at run time it does not works, since the Menu is inside a path defined in the ControlTemplate of a Symbol which is not a FrameworkElement!

I have added a name for the ContextMenu, but I am not able to retrieve it from the ViewModel (where I create the graphic and the symbol; if I were able to do that, I would be able to add the desired datacontext in code:

```
      var graphic = new Graphic { Symbol = Resources["PolylineSymbol"] as SimpleLineSymbol;
      var menu = graphic.Symbol.ControlTemplate.FindName("popUpMenu", graphic.Symbol); // ???
      menu.DataContext = graphic;
```

)

Any Ideas, please?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, it seems as though you have a common problem in WPF. The solution is to utilise a `Tag` property of your `Path` to 'pass' the `DataContext` through to the `ContextMenu` using the [`ContextMenu.PlacementTarget` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contextmenu.placementtarget%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This *Gets or sets the UIElement relative to which the ContextMenu is positioned when it opens*. Try this:

```
<Path x:Name="Element" Fill="{x:Null}" Stroke="Navy" StrokeThickness="3"
    StrokeLineJoin="Round" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round"
    Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type 
    esri:Graphic}}}"><!--Use Binding.Path that you need for data here-->
    <Path.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu x:Name="popUpMenu" DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag, 
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"><!--Use PlacementTarget.Tag-->
            <MenuItem x:Name="miSelect" Header="Select" IsCheckable="True"
                IsChecked="{Binding Selected, FallbackValue=False}" />
            ...
        </ContextMenu>
    </Path.ContextMenu>
</Path>
```

Comment: In the designer, Tag in PlacementTarget.Tag is underlined with the error "Cannot resolve property 'Tag' in data context of type 'System.Windows.UIElement'"

In execution I get: 
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Graphic', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:(no path); DataItem=null; target element is 'Path' (Name='Element'); target property is 'Tag' (type 'Object')

Comment: I think, there are two issues here:
1. "Path" is UIElement, which does not have a tag, unless I'll be able to typecast to Path.
2. Grid.Path are part of GraphicElement, which is declared internal, so FindAncestor cannot get over...

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to implement the Opened even of the Context menu. In the code behind I assign the instance of the view model on its DataContext.

```
    <Path.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu 
                    Opened="PopUpMenu_OnOpened"
            >
```

code behind:

```
    private void PopUpMenu_OnOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var menu = sender as ContextMenu;
        if (menu != null)
        {
            menu.DataContext = ViewModel;
        }
    }
```

Another challenge was to get the clicked graphic and the clicked point.
The solution was to create properties in the View model and assign both on LeftMouseDown and RightMouseDown.

```
    private Graphic GetPolylineGraphic(ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry.Geometry geometry = null)
    {
        var drawLayer = Model.GetDrawLayer(MyMap, "Polyline");
        var graphic = new Graphic
        {
            // clone the resourced PolylineSymbol (from Model)
            Symbol = new SimpleLineSymbol 
                {
                    Color = PolylineSymbol.Color,
                    Width = PolylineSymbol.Width,
                    ControlTemplate = PolylineSymbol.ControlTemplate
                }
        };

        if (geometry != null) graphic.Geometry = geometry;

        graphic.MouseLeftButtonDown += GraphicOnMouseLeftButtonDown;
        graphic.MouseRightButtonDown += GraphicOnMouseRightButtonDown;
        drawLayer.Graphics.Add(graphic);

        return graphic;
    }

    private Graphic m_clickedGraphic;
    public Graphic ClickedGraphic
    {
        get { return m_clickedGraphic; }
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(m_clickedGraphic, value))
            {
                m_clickedGraphic = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(value);
            }
        }
    }

    private MapPoint m_clickedPoint;
    public MapPoint ClickedPoint
    {
        get { return m_clickedPoint; }
        set
        {
            if (m_clickedPoint != value)
            {
                m_clickedPoint = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(value);
            }
        }
    }

    private void GraphicOnMouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs args)
    {
        //// This does not work because GraphicElement is internal!!!
        //var s = args.Source; 
        //ClickedGraphic = ((GraphicElement)(e.Source)).Graphic;
        //ClickedPoint = ((GraphicElement)(e.Source)).Origin;
        ClickedGraphic = sender as Graphic;
        ClickedPoint = MyMap.ScreenToMap(args.GetPosition(MyMap));

        //// not here - else context menu won't pop!
        //args.Handled = true;
    }

    private void GraphicOnMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs args)
    {
        var g = sender as Graphic;
        if (g != null)
        {
            ClickedGraphic = g;
            ClickedPoint = MyMap.ScreenToMap(args.GetPosition(MyMap));

            // select/unselect the graphic on left click
            if (g.Selected) g.UnSelect();
            else g.Select();
            args.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

To make everything work, I had to clone the symbol.